# Installing Openfire or Ejabberd Server on Azure

Tags: azure, ejabberd, openfire

I am just subscribe to the windows azure account. I am planning to run openfire/ejabber server on windows azure. I have created windows server 2012 virtual machine on azure. But I cannot find a way how to install openfire or ejabber server on azure virtual machine.

`Is it possible to install openfire/ejabber server on azure virtual machine?` Since I have a xmpp application running on android and openfire server on localhost.

```
If it is possible please guide me through this.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to install both Openfire or ejabberd server on Azure virtual machine. Speaking for ejabberd, there is nothing specific to Azure. You can just install ejabberd from binary installer as downloaded from ProcessOne site: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

You can for example select a Linux Ubuntu Azure instance and deploy ejabberd on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to install openfire or ejabbered on azure virtual machine. You have to download binary file on your machine. and then copy that downloaded binary file to virtual machine created on azure. After copied, you have to install it and on virtual machine. And donot forget to create Endpoint.